# Mail sent via SMTP Marked as SPAM but Direct Emails are OKAY

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I've seen similar Questions BUT my case is: The direct emails sent from the account aren't filtered while the mail sent through SMTP are collected as SPAM.

I purchased Email Services for my Company (support@website.com) and whenn I send emails through this email to my customers, they get marked as spam. This happens when I send emails via ASP.NET's SMTP service:

```
   MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("support@website.com", email);
   mm.Subject = "Welcome, " + name;
   string body = "Hello " + name + ",";
   mm.Body = body;
   mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
   mm.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
   smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("support@website.com", "MY_PASS");
   smtp.EnableSsl = true;
   smtp.Send(mm);
```

When I **directly send the emails, they don't get filtered**. There's something missing in the code I assume?

Comment: When you say "directly send" do you mean from the email provider's webmail? Does that by any chance send emails as HTML?  External plain text emails are often more susceptible to spam filtering.

Comment: Also, are your customers using public email providers (outlook/Gmail etc.)? Some providers such as outlook, are often more strict around mail filtering.

Comment: I realized that this happens when I add an <img> tag with an image as the src to the email through smtp. How can I work arounnd this? @Ahhhhbisto